# Outlook 2007 not showing desktop alerts unless I repeatedly uninstall an automatic update

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, windows-update

I have some strange issue with Outlook 2007 on Windows 7. I am not getting desktop alerts whenever I receive emails. I checked all necessary configuration.

After some research I found that if I uninstall Microsoft Update for Office Outlook 2007 (KB2288953) it works fine and I can see desktop alerts.

But every morning I have to do it again after Windows Update.

Can any one help me to get permament solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened. But today I am able to see Desktop Alerts without any issue as before. I feel that is resolved due to next windows update. I am trying to search which KB update resolved my issue. I will share with you guys once I find.

Answer (score 0):

This registry fix may also help:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\DesktopAlerts]
"Opacity"=dword:000000d4
"TimeOn"=dword:00006978
"XOffset"=dword:00000005
"YOffset"=dword:00000005
"Corner"=dword:00000003
```